# What determines your jump height?

Tags: jet-set-radio

The jump button appears to be unrelated to the height of the jump. Beat (the first character) appears to have two jumps: short and huge backflip. Are there other kinds of jumps or is this dichotomy accurate?

What determines the height of the jump? Is it related to when Beat says "Yeah!" or "Nice!"? Is it related to the score or current combo? Is it related to the length of time grinding or boosting before jumping? Does this change between characters? Not knowing this complicates my path-planning.

Specifically, when attempting a large combo in the tutorial my second or third short jump button presses on the large rail result in a Method Back Flip or Flying Kite. How can I predict when this will happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jump height is based on how hard you press the jump button.  A quick tap makes for a shorter jump, and mashing the button does a larger jump.

The huge backflip is automatically done on a jump off of a grind when going fast enough, and counts as an air trick.  And, a normal jump will be done if moving slowly on a rail.

"Yeah!" and "Nice!" simply mean you successfully did a trick.  The more tricks you do in succession, before touching the ground, the faster you will grind.  Boosting also increases speed.  The more speed you have (JSRF has a speed meter, I don't remember if JSR does), the further you will jump, but not higher.

Comment: I still get huge backflips on short presses. Is it just that every few jumps is a huge backflip? (See added case in topic.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure air tricks always happen when jumping from a rail if going a certain speed.  It won't trigger if going too slowly.  It may not trigger on the 1st jump because you're not fast enough yet, but will on the 2nd or 3rd jump because you've built some speed.  I'll confirm later and update as needed.